# Crash report - what does it say and how to solve?

Tags: android, image, memory-management

Can anybody please explain what is this problem and tell me what would be the solution?
My app uses a listview that inflates and shows images in it. The images are very small size just a few kbs (less than 20 kbs each) ....some views have only one or two images in the list but some have up to 12 images.

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:677)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:507)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:872)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3022)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1586)
at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:648)
at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:377)
at com.admads.android.HisnulMuslim_Google_JQM.DuaAdapter.getView(DuaAdapter.java:78)
at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:230)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2707)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1801)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:697)
at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:661)
at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:6651)
at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3916)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove(AbsListView.java:4756)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:4582)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8093)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2129)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2411)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2144)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2411)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2144)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2411)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2144)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2411)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2144)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2252)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1587)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2507)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2200)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8301)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4531)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4403)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3961)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4015)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3984)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4095)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3992)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4152)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3961)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4015)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3984)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3992)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3961)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6320)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6222)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6193)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6158)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6400)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:6373)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6419)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:571)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code for Main activity [ the main part]

```
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        context = getApplicationContext();
        setContentView(R.layout.myact);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        final DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(context);
        try {db.createDataBase();} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        db.openDataBase();  

        if (savedInstanceState == null) { }

        cd = db.getDetsById(iid);

        dualist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dua_list);

        prepareList();

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mAdapter1 = new DuaAdapter(getApplicationContext(),duaItems);
        dualist.setAdapter(mAdapter1);

        db.close();

        prevbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                currentDua--;
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                intent.putExtra("iid", currentDua);
                finish();startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
            }
        });
        nxtbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                currentDua++;
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                intent.putExtra("iid", currentDua);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
            }
        });

    public void prepareList() {
          duaItems = new ArrayList<DuaItem>();
          cd.moveToFirst();
          do {

              duaItems.add(new DuaItem(isTopV, cd.getString(1), isImgV, cd.getString(2), isAudV, cd.getString(3),isTransV, cd.getString(4), isTranslitV, cd.getString(5)));

          } while (cd.moveToNext());

    }
```

the adapter class[the main part]

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_dua, null);
        }

        TextView textViewTop = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTop);
        ImageView imageViewDua = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewDua);
        final Button btnPP = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.playpause);
        TextView txtViewTranslation = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewTranslation);
        TextView txtViewTransliteration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewTransliteration);

        textViewTop.setText(Html.fromHtml(duaItems.get(position).getTop()));


        int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(duaItems.get(position).getImage(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());
        imageViewDua.setImageResource(resId);

        txtViewTranslation.setText(t1);

        txtViewTransliteration.setText(t2);

        final int audId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(duaItems.get(position).getAudio(), "raw",context.getPackageName());
        btnPP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mPlayer.reset(); btnPP.setText("c");
                        } else {
                        mPlayer.release(); mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, audId);
                        //try { mPlayer.prepare(); } catch (IllegalStateException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                        mPlayer.start(); btnPP.setText("a");
                        mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() { public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            mPlayer.reset(); mPlayer.release(); btnPP.setText("c");}
                        });
                    } 

                }
            });



        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` is the cause and you could look @ `DuaAdapter.java` line 78. Fix scale down the image

Comment: Just simply providing you error dosen't make sense.say us what you're trying do and where do you get this problem ?